# how to display dynamically chart in each cell?

Tags: javascript, html, highcharts

Dynamically need to generate id every time. 
i did but i put hard code data. 
again and again i call this code using different id, i want to do using loop, so any suggestion?

Can you suggest me how to do or any other method?

**JS:**

```
$(function() {
  $('#container').highcharts({
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      //categories: ['Work Center 1']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'percent'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Booked Order',
      data: [5]
    }, {
      name: 'Urgent Order',
      data: [2]
    }, {
      name: 'Available',
      data: [3]
    }]
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Month1</td>
    <td>
      <div id="container" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container1" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container2" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container3" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container4" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this ??

```js
$(function() {
  var chartData = {
    chart: {
      type: 'bar'
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      //categories: ['Work Center 1']
    },
    yAxis: {
      min: 0,
      title: {
        text: ''
      }
    },
    legend: {
      reversed: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        stacking: 'percent'
      }
    },
    series: [{
      name: 'Booked Order',
      data: [5]
    }, {
      name: 'Urgent Order',
      data: [2]
    }, {
      name: 'Available',
      data: [3]
    }]
  };

  $('div[id^=container]').each(function() {
    $(this).highcharts(chartData);
  });;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/highcharts/4.2.6/highcharts.js"></script>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td>Month1</td>
    <td>
      <div id="container" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container1" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container2" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container3" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="container4" style="width: 250px; height: 200px; margin: 0 auto; "></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: thanks for your suggestion but i want chart in each cell of the table. @pugazh